# How to set Background and TextColor from Theme in Styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-background, android-text-color

This seems a pretty basic task, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have several activities that all contain buttons that I want styled the same. I have defined the following styles in `styles.xml` and applied them as themes to the buttons in `view.aml`.

All the items from `styles.xml` appear to be applied to each button correctly, except `android:textColor` and `android:background`, these are still displayed as the default grey gradient and black text. Is this the correct way of doing this? Where am I going wrong?

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <resources>
      <style name="button">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">50px</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">50px</item>
        <item name="android:height">50px</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">50px</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">50px</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30px</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/background_light</item>
      </style>
      <style name="button.grey">
        <item name="android:background">@color/grey</item>
      </style>
      <style name="button.primary">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
      </style>
    </resources>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <item name="grey" type="color">#CCCCCC</item>
  <item name="primary" type="color">#40B837</item>
</resources>
```

**view.axml**

```
<Button
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/detailsNextBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/button.grey"/>
```

**Android Manifest.xml**

```
    <application android:label="myApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"></application>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What are the themes of your activities? Try to extend Theme.Light.NoTitleBar theme, define your colors there and use it for activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace this:

```
<style name="button">
```

for this:

```
<style name="button" parent="android:Widget.Button">
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but the still display the same.